# pub get failed on pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  quickalert: ^1.0.1
```

I tried to run pub get, but it failed (i live in Syria; I don't know if the location is the problem)

This is the link to the package I want to use https://pub.dev/packages/quickalert/install

so please help

```
flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in puzzel...                          
Authentication error (403)
package:pub/src/authentication/client.dart 95:5    _AuthenticatedClient._throwAuthException
package:pub/src/authentication/client.dart 60:9    _AuthenticatedClient.send
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/authentication/client.dart 133:12  withAuthenticatedClient
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 862:22          HostedSource._download.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/io.dart 886:12                     withTempDir
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 859:5           HostedSource._download
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 669:7           HostedSource.downloadToSystemCache
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/result.dart 86:9            SolveResult.downloadCachedPackages.<fn>.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/result.dart 85:14           SolveResult.downloadCachedPackages.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/result.dart 82:5            SolveResult.downloadCachedPackages
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 332:7              Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/command/get.dart 55:5              GetCommand.runProtected
This is an unexpected error. The full log and other details are collected in:

    C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\log\pub_log.txt

Consider creating an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
and attaching the relevant parts of that log file.
pub get failed (1; and attaching the relevant parts of that log file.)
exit code 1
```

Comment: can you access pub.dev website..?

Comment: what's that for ?

Comment: Have you tried using VPN to do pub get?

Comment: what is your flutter version?

Comment: I tried to use VPN and it did not work ,my flutter version 3.3.2